# How can I run multiple classes sequentially using testng?

Tags: xml, testing, automation, testng

Actually what I have to do is I have to run the browser and in that single browser I have to run say, two classes
English.java
German.java
And after that, I have have to close the browser.
So how should I create my tenstng.xml to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your testng.xml have to look like this

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >


<suite name="ABC" parallel="classes">

  <test name="HomePageTest">
    <classes>
      <class name="selenium.tests.HomePageTest"/>
      <class name="selenium.tests.LoginPageTest"/>>
    </classes>
  </test>

</suite>
```

Comment: bro that's opening two browsers but I have to do it on a single one

Comment: @vishalrathi I'm afraid you cannot somehow change it. Because parallel execution could be done only on separate opened browser session.

Comment: No, it's not executed parallelly it's executing one by one but it opens the first browser execute the class one closes it and then opens the second browser and executes but I want is it only one browser and execute both the classes.